# System.Data.Common.DbCommand: Parameterized Query as Procedure Parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have procedure in PostgreSQL defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CreateCursorC(text, text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE c
AS '$libdir/mylibs', $function$createcursorc$function$
```

Execute example:

```
SELECT CreateCursorC('cursor_name', 'SELECT a FROM x WHERE a=''text''');
```

Of course I would like to use parameters (DbCommand.Parameters). Like this:

```
SELECT CreateCursorC($1, 'SELECT a FROM x WHERE a=$2');
```

Unfortunately it's not working because parameter $2 is in quotes.
Is there a way to accomplished this task using parameters and **not by writing custom SQL escaping function**?

I tried to get an answer at Devart Forum, but no luck:
[Parameterized Query as Procedure Parameter? | Devart Forums](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29726)

Comment: Some background would be helpful here. Why does the second parameter being quoted matter? What does this function do, and why do you have to pass it SQL text? What exactly "does not work" - what happens, and what should happen instead? What's the error message? PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Generally: no, it is not. Parameters are like variables in compiled languages - and you can not put source code in there and execute it.

Comment: In fact you can. Function is written in C. It creates cursor, count rows and returns position of last "selected" row. This function is much faster than standard operations using cursors. The only problem is how to pass parameters to query in secure way.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Do you need help understanding how to setup parameterized queries in C# code?

Comment: @dblood No. I know how to do it. Problem is how to pass parameterized query as parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your issue. I ran into a similar problem when trying to setup a parameterized query that included a LIKE expression in MySQL, via C#.

The trick that I found, in the case of the LIKE expression, was to make the % characters part of the parameter. In your case, this same type of logic may work for your quoted text.

Here's a snippet of code showing what I did in my case:

```
IDBCommandParameters cmdParams = dbContext.CreateDBCommandParameters();

cmdParams.AddParameter(QueryConstants.likeParam, string.Format("%{0}%", likeFilter));

List<TQueryResult> companies = LoadModelList<TQueryResult>(dbContext.Find(QueryConstants.findCompaniesLikeStatement, cmdParams, false), "");

return companies;
```